# What is the right way to have an onKeyPress event in Yii?

Tags: javascript, php, yii, yii2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textCnt(textarea, counterID, maxLen)
{
    var $cnt = document.getElementById(counterID);
    if (textarea.value.length > maxLen)
    {
        textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,maxLen);
    }
    $cnt.innerHTML = maxLen - textarea.value.length + '/500';
}    
</script>

<div class="row">
            <div id="counter">
            500/500
            </div>
                <?php echo $form->labelEx($modelAdd,'AdditionalText'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textArea($modelAdd,'AdditionalText', 
array('maxlength'=>300, 'rows' => 5, 'cols' =>90, 'name'=>'AdditionalText', 
'id'=>'AdditionalText',

'onkeypress'=>'textCnt($this, "counter", 500)', 
'onChange'=>'textCnt($this, "counter", 500)', 'type'=>'raw'));   
                ?>

</div>
```

I have a textCnt function which is supposed to count the length of the textarea and then minus it from the amount that I am passing into the function. I must have the syntax wrong as I am getting the following error "Uncaught ReferenceError: textCnt is not defined
  at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeypress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing PHP var and javscript so the javascript code fails and you have not the function
You should NOT use `$cnt` but `cnt`

```
function textCnt(textarea, counterID, maxLen)
{
   var cnt = document.getElementById(counterID);
   if (textarea.value.length > maxLen)
   {
       textarea.value = textarea.value.substring(0,maxLen);
   }
   cnt.innerHTML = (maxLen - textarea.value.length) + '/500';
}
```

and in your call  you should use `this` and NOT `$this`

```
 'onkeypress'=>'textCnt(this, "counter", 500);',
```

Comment: I just made both of those changes which was how I had it originally. However, it still is giving me those errors. What else could be wrong?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: textCnt is not defined
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.onkeypress

Comment: For some reason the textCnt is not declare  .. i have  slightly modified the answer with () around the length calculation .. but check if you have some error in javascript

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. I entered a line before the function and that seemed to have done the trick.